# C++ Hangman with a class

Tags: c++, hangman

Well, hang-bar but same deal.

Any things I could've improved? (I'm starting to get into c++, so chose this as a basic project)

Actually, one question I had: I'm using code::blocks, which generates class headers+implementation files, but places the headers in an `include` folder while the implementation files go in `src`. I noticed that the code wouldn't compile in code::blocks till I added the compiler setting of `-Iinclude`. I assume that means it checks `/include` each time it wants to find a header, but that seems sorta weird that you would need to add that. Is it better practice to do that, or to just write the includes with full paths (e.g. the implementation of HangmanGame would have `#include ../include/HangmanGame.h`)?

One other question: I'm reasonably sure that some of the `#include`s from the STL are no longer needed (I removed whatever was using them), is there a tool in code::blocks (or another program) that allows me to easily see which `#include`s are currently not used? Since every `std::something` call comes from one `#include` or another, I would think there'd be some easy way to check that out.

Any feedback on that or other aspects appreciated.

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "HangmanGame.h"

#define RUNNING 0

int main()
{
    HangmanGame game;
    while (game.performTurn() == RUNNING) {};
    return 0;
}
```

`HangmanGame.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef HANGMANGAME_H
#define HANGMANGAME_H
#include <string>
#include <set>

class HangmanGame
{
public:
    HangmanGame();

    int performTurn();

private:
    void printMan();
    void printGuessWord();
    void printWrongGuesses();

    static std::string getRandomWord();

    char getGuess();

    void winGame();
    void loseGame();

    const std::string secretWord;
    std::set<char> guessedLetters = {};
    std::set<char> guessedWrongLetters = {};

};

#endif // HANGMANGAME_H
```

`HangmanGame.cpp`:

````cpp
#include "HangmanGame.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#define RUNNING 0
#define WIN 1
#define LOSE -1

HangmanGame::HangmanGame() : secretWord(getRandomWord()) {}

void HangmanGame::printMan()
{
    std::cout << "|------------------------|\n|";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        std::cout << ((i < guessedWrongLetters.size()) ? "\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588" : "    ");
    }
    std::cout << "|\n|------------------------|" << std::endl;
}

void HangmanGame::printGuessWord()
{
    std::istringstream wordStream (secretWord);
    char letter;

    while (wordStream >> letter) {
        std::cout << ((guessedLetters.find(letter) == guessedLetters.end()) ? '_' : letter) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void HangmanGame::printWrongGuesses()
{
    for (char letter : guessedWrongLetters) {
        std::cout << letter << " ";
    }
    if (guessedLetters.size() > 0)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

std::string HangmanGame::getRandomWord()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::ifstream file("words.txt");
    std::string line;

    srand(time(0));
    while(getline(file,line)) words.push_back(line);
    std::random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());
    return words[0];
}

char HangmanGame::getGuess()
{
    std::string inputStr;
    std::locale loc;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter a letter: " << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, inputStr);
        std::transform(inputStr.begin(), inputStr.end(), inputStr.begin(), ::tolower);
        if (inputStr.length() != 1) {
            std::cout << "Please enter one letter!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        if ((guessedLetters.find(inputStr[0]) != guessedLetters.end())) {
            std::cout << "You've already guessed that letter!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (!isalpha(inputStr[0])) {
            std::cout << "Please enter a letter!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        return inputStr[0];
    }
}

int HangmanGame::performTurn()
{
    std::cout << "Hang-o-meter (Don't let it fill up!!)" << std::endl;
    printMan();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Wrong guesses:" << std::endl;
    printWrongGuesses();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Word:" << std::endl;
    printGuessWord();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    char guess = getGuess();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    guessedLetters.insert(guess);
    if (std::count(secretWord.begin(), secretWord.end(), guess) > 0) {
        std::cout << guess << " appears " << std::count(secretWord.begin(), secretWord.end(), guess) << " times in the word!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << guess << " doesn't appear in the word." << std::endl;
        guessedWrongLetters.insert(guess);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    if (guessedWrongLetters.size() >= 6) {
        loseGame();
        return LOSE;
    }

    for (char c : secretWord) {
        if (guessedLetters.find(c) == guessedLetters.end()) {
            return RUNNING;
        }
    }

    winGame();
    return WIN;

}

void HangmanGame::winGame()
{
    std::cout << "You win!" << std::endl << std::endl;
    printMan();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The word was:" << std::endl;
    printGuessWord();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void HangmanGame::loseGame()
{
    std::cout << "You lose!" << std::endl << std::endl;
    printMan();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::istringstream wordStream(secretWord);
    auto begin = std::istream_iterator<char>(wordStream);
    auto end = std::istream_iterator<char>();
    std::set<char> temp(begin, end);
    guessedLetters = temp;

    std::cout << "The word was:" << std::endl;
    printGuessWord();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Constants

Instead of macros, use `constexpr` or `enum`, and put the constants in
a header file rather than duplicate them multiple times:

```cpp
enum class Status {
    Running, Win, Lose
};
```

## Default constructor

Generally, I would expect default constructors to be lightweight.  I
would make the secret word an argument of the constructor:

```cpp
#include <utility>

class HangmanGame {
    std::string secret_word;
    // ...
public:
    explicit HangmanGame(std::string secret_word)
        : secret_word{std::move(secret_word)}
    {
    }
    // ...
};
```

so that the class can be used with both set-word and random-word
games.

## Random word generation

Instead of storing all words in memory, you can scan the file to find
out the number of words and scan the file again to pick the `n`th
word.

## Miscellaneous

[Use `\n`, not `std::endl`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907)

In `printGuessWord` and `loseGame`, the letters of a `std::string` can
be directly iterated over.  There is no need to construct a
`std::istringstream` for this.

This works, but is technically unsound:

```cpp
std::transform(inputStr.begin(), inputStr.end(), inputStr.begin(), ::tolower);
```

In the eyes of a language lawyer, it should be replaced by

```cpp
std::transform(
    inputStr.begin(), inputStr.end(), inputStr.begin(),
    [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); }
);
```

(see [Do I need to cast to `unsigned char` before calling `toupper()`,
`tolower()`, et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805970)).

In

```cpp
int main()
{
    HangmanGame game;
    while (game.performTurn() == RUNNING) {};
    return 0;
}
```

the game logic is usually contained within a `.run()` method.

## Q & A

> Actually, one question I had: I'm using code::blocks, which
> generates class headers+implementation files, but places the headers
> in an `include` folder while the implementation files go in `src`. I
> noticed that the code wouldn't compile in code::blocks till I added
> the compiler setting of `-Iinclude`. I assume that means it checks
> `/include` each time it wants to find a header, but that seems sorta
> weird that you would need to add that. Is it better practice to do
> that, or to just write the includes with full paths (e.g. the
> implementation of HangmanGame would have `#include ../include/HangmanGame.h`)?

I would go with `-Iinclude`.  This way, the code is independent from
the organization of the source files is.  You can modify the placement
of files later without touching the code.

> One other question: I'm reasonably sure that some of the `#include`s
> from the STL are no longer needed (I removed whatever was using
> them), is there a tool in code::blocks (or another program) that
> allows me to easily see which `#include`s are currently not used?
> Since every `std::something` call comes from one `#include` or
> another, I would think there'd be some easy way to check that out.

I'm not sure about Code::Blocks, but in general, I wouldn't worry
about this too much.  In fact, one common practice is to put all
`#include`s from the standard library to a precompiled header, so as
not to slow down (and sometimes even speed up) compilation.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - by the way, would it make sense to put the enum in the same header, or a different one?

Comment: @Theo The enum is going to be used as the return type of `performTurn`, and thus it is part of the public interface, so yes, it should be put in the same header.  Alternatively, if you make `performTurn` private and expose only a `run` function, you can make the enum internal to the implementation.